# Why my circuit breaker is always open by default and doesn't work upon minimumNumberOfCalls from properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I am new to implementing the circuit breaker functionality in spring boot. I have added all the required dependencies in build.gradle file and the circuit breaker annotation on the method which on exception goes to the fallback method so I know that the circuit breaker dependency is working. The problem is, that the circuit breaker is always open and doesn't work based on the circuit breaker properties set in application.yml file. I'll explain what I added by code snippets.

**My build.gradle file has the dependency:**

````
```implementation('io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:1.6.1')```
````

**Controller:**

```
@GET
     @Path("product/{id}")
       public Response getProduct(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
            logger.info("demo-service called for productId {}", id);
            return Response.ok(userService.getProduct(id)).build();
     }
```

**Service:**

```
@CircuitBreaker(name = "demoServiceCircuitBreaker", fallbackMethod = "demoServiceFallbackMethod")
    public ProductResponse getProduct(Integer id) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Service is in error");
    }

 public ProductResponse demoServiceFallbackMethod(Integer id, Exception exc) {
            logger.error("Got an error, executing fallbackmethod and returning default from application");
            return defaultProduct();
     }
     
 public ProductResponse defaultProduct() {
        ProductResponse productResponse = new ProductResponse();
        productResponse.setId(999);
        productResponse.setName("Free coffee");
        productResponse.setPrice(0.0);
        return productResponse;
    }
```

**application.yml**

```
resilience4j:
    circuitbreaker:
        configs:
          default:
            failureRateThreshold: 50                 #  Configures the failure rate threshold in percentage. When the failure rate is equal or greater than the threshold the CircuitBreaker transitions to open and starts short-circuiting calls. 
            slowCallRateThreshold: 50                # Configures a threshold in percentage. The CircuitBreaker considers a call as slow when the call duration is greater than slowCallDurationThreshold
            slowCallDurationThreshold: PT5S          # Configures the duration threshold above which calls are considered as slow and increase the rate of slow calls.
            permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3 # Configures the number of permitted calls when the CircuitBreaker is half open.
            slidingWindowType: COUNT_BASED           # If the sliding window is COUNT_BASED, the last slidingWindowSize calls are recorded and aggregated.
            slidingWindowSize: 10                    # Configures the size of the sliding window which is used to record the outcome of calls when the CircuitBreaker is closed.
            minimumNumberOfCalls: 2                  # Configures the minimum number of calls which are required (per sliding window period) before the CircuitBreaker can calculate the error rate or slow call rate.
            waitDurationInOpenState: PT5S            # The time that the CircuitBreaker should wait before transitioning from open to half-open.
            #recordExceptions:
            #   - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
             #  - java.io.IOException
              # - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
               #- org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException
    instances:
         demoServiceCircuitBreaker:
            baseConfig: default
```

Whenever I hit the endpoint, it returns the ProductResponse in json (from fallback method). It doesn't see the minimum number of calls when the monitoring needs to be started or even the failure threshold is ignored. I expect to see the exception (Service is in error) first in first 2 calls and then finally after the threshold is reached it should return the ProductResponse in json.

Kindly help me figure out what I missed here. Tried removing a few configs from application.yml but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration and properties are correct. The circuit breaker will open only after the `minimumNumberOfCalls` are recorded.

The reason for the above ProductResponse is due to the [fallback mechanism of Resilience4J](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#fallback-methods).

> If a fallback method is configured, every exception is forwarded to a fallback method executor. The fallback method executor is searching for the best matching fallback method which can handle the exception

Henceforth, narrow down the scope of argument of fallback method from `Exception` to `CallNotPermittedException`

```
public ProductResponse demoServiceFallbackMethod(Integer id, CallNotPermittedException exc) {
            logger.error("Got an error, executing fallbackmethod and returning default from application");
            return defaultProduct();
     }
```